# Django: updating form instance with onetoone relationship without raising IntegrityError

Tags: python, django

I'm currently building this ordering app, and I'm having difficulties maintaining `OneToOne` relationships. For the context of this problem, I have two models:

```
# models.py

class Order(models.Model):
    # stuff

class DeliveryOptions(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, related_name='order_delivery_options')
```

The ordering process is a 4-page collection of different forms. But I also wanted to make it so you can go back to one of the pages(forms) you have already completed and change something. So I have `get` load the form instance in the view below:

```
class MyView(generic.FormView):
    # this would be one of the views of 4 for the ordering process
    # ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = actions.get_order(request)
        try:
            delivery_options = order.order_delivery_options
            form = DeliveryOptionsForm(instance=delivery_options, order=order)
        except AttributeError:
            form = DeliveryOptionsForm(order=order)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = actions.get_order(request)
        form = DeliveryOptionsForm(request.POST, order=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            self.form_valid(order, form)
        else:
            self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, order, form):
        delivery_options = form.save(commit = False)
        delivery_options.order = order
        delivery_options.save()
        order.save()
        return redirect('orders:order-payment')

    #...
```

Now the problem arrises in the `post` function when you are saving a previously saved form. I get an `IntegrityError` because it says I'm saving 2 `DeliveryOption` models to the same `Order`, even though I'm loading the instance that is attributed to the order in `get`.

So I'm thinking that the problem must be that in `post` I'm saving a new `DeliveryOptions` instance, when really I just want to be updating the old one. Will `form = DeliveryOptionsForm(request.POST, instance=instance, order=order)` work as intended if `instance` is the previous instance? Not sure how to handle this properly.

Comment: `The ordering process is a 4-page collection of different forms` - you should use form wizard in such cases.

Comment: @Rohan Never heard of it, thanks! Should make things much easier!